# facebook api with android

Tags: android

I am new to facebook api and android.But somehow try  to manage login to my facebook account and retrieve some information of my account i.e. id,first_name,last_name.The sdk(android) which is used on creating this application is sdk(android) level 8 but when i used sdk(android) level >8 application crash and error generate on logcat(networkonmainthreadException).I had done some search and found this is thread problem with sdk level and now i am going for Asynctask but got confused where to put the login code for facebook and what thing will return to mainactivity

My code for sdk level 8 is:-

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);
        loginnfetch=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        loginnfetch.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                facebook=new Facebook(APP_ID);
                restorecredential(facebook);
                if(!facebook.isSessionValid())
                {
                    loginandfetch();
                }
                else
                {
                    fetch();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    protected void fetch() 
    {
        try {
            JSONObject jobj=new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
            int id=jobj.getInt("id");
            String fname=jobj.getString("first_name");
            String lname=jobj.getString("last_name");
            //String emailid=jobj.getString("email");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ".."+id+".."+fname+".."+lname, 0).show();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected void loginandfetch() 
    {
        facebook.authorize(this, PERMISSIONS, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH,new DialogListener() {

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR WHILE LOGIN", 0).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR WHILE LOGIN", 0).show();


            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                saveCredentials(facebook);
                fetch();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "ERROR WHILE LOGIN", 0).show();

            }
        });

    }

    protected boolean restorecredential(Facebook facebook2) 
    {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext()
                .getSharedPreferences(KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        facebook.setAccessToken(sharedPreferences.getString(TOKEN, null));
        facebook.setAccessExpires(sharedPreferences.getLong(EXPIRES, 0));
        return facebook.isSessionValid();

    }
    public boolean saveCredentials(Facebook facebook) {
        Editor editor = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(KEY,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString(TOKEN, facebook.getAccessToken());
        editor.putLong(EXPIRES, facebook.getAccessExpires());
        return editor.commit();
    }
```

Please share some code if available or some link
thank you and sorry if something is not correct

Answer (score 0):

From the ICS and above versions Android won't allowed any network operation in the UI thread.It should be done in separate thread so it won't hang the UI.Try your network communication code in the separate thread.
In your case,fetch facebook info using thread.

Try this ::

```
if(!facebook.isSessionValid())
{
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                loginandfetch();
            }
        }).start();
}
else
{
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fetch();
            }
        }).start();
}
```

Comment: I am using AsyncTask please help me on that

Comment: where have you used AsyncTask() ?

Comment: Here is my code for Asynctask please check and let me know if something is missing:public void onClick(View v) 
 {
  switch(v.getId())
  {
  case R.id.button1:
   Loginnfetchtask task=new Loginnfetchtask();
   task.execute(APP_ID);
   break;private class Loginnfetchtask extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Long>
 {

  
  @Override
  protected Long doInBackground(String... params) {
   facebook=new Facebook(APP_ID);
   restorecrediantial(facebook);
   if(!facebook.isSessionValid())

Comment: update your answer and paste this code over there for a better look :)

Comment: share your file over the net and let me knw :)

Comment: In your code try this way (don't forget to initialize the handler):: handler.post(new Runnable() {

     public void run() {
      task.execute(APP_ID);
     }
    });
    break;

Answer (score 0):

I have posted status on facebook like bellow. you can try something like this for your problem: (Facebook api 3.02b)

```
Request.Callback callback= new Request.Callback() {                 
    public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
        if (error != null) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Failed to Post", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Successfully Posted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};
Request request = new Request(session, victimId+"/feed", bundle, 
                                  HttpMethod.POST, callback);

RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
task.execute();
```